# Wireless card only starts to work if I boot into Windows

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I'm facing a very weird problem with my wireless network card in ubuntu 10.10 !

Recently I have installed ubuntu 10.10 beside my windows XP on my Dell XPS 1330 laptop.
Everything worked fine except my wireless network. I tried to activate the wireless driver recommended in "Ubuntu Additional Drivers" utiltity, but it didn't work.
Next, I installed "ndisWrapper-utils" using "Synaptic Package Manager" and installed my windows wireless driver using "Windows Wireless Driver" utility!

Now it is sometimes working fine, sometimes not!!

The weird thing is that whenever my ubuntu doesn't recognize my wireless network and I restart my computer to my windows XP; My Windows doesn't recognize the wireless networks too! In this situation if I restart my windows, the problem still isn't solved BUT if I standby my windows and come back, the problem is solved in both windows and linux!!!

It means that whenever my ubuntu doesn't recognize my wireless network, I have to restart in my windows and stanby for once and come back in my ubuntu !!! :D

```
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02)
0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
```

Comment: Do u use a broadcom adapter?

Comment: Could you please provide us information about the device? do a `lspci -vv` command into a terminal and paste the output at http://paste.ubuntu.com/. Thanks!

Comment: This will help you find the logs you need to paste: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Comment: Thank you, I did it. Is there any more information I can provide?

Comment: chk this link : http://askubuntu.com/questions/59296/how-do-i-get-wifi-working-on-my-hp-pavilion-dv2000-laptop?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

Is there an on/off button for your wireless?  If so, try pressing that in Ubuntu. It might be off by default when it boots into Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, Of course I have checked that. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

"The weird thing is that whenever my ubuntu doesn't recognize my wireless network and I restart my computer to my windows XP; My Windows doesn't recognize the wireless networks too!"

This may simply (or at least partially) be something new conflicting with your wireless network.  Otherwise your wireless adapter is Broadcom and so takes some extra work to get working properly ([Look here](http://life.firelace.com/2010/10/tips-and-tricks-upgrading-to-ubuntu-10-10-wireless-fix/) and [here](http://ubuntu-ky.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1594577)).