# HP 2000 Wireless don't work with Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, hp

I just got the last version 12.10-64bits, to install in my new HP 2000, and everything went fine, including the EFI installation in the original Windows 8 platform (I've followed this tutorial https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI).

The only problem is that WiFi don't work. Anyone has passed by the same problem? If you need any information about the hardware, just tell me how I get it and I'll get it.

---

Here goes the outputs:

`lspci`:

```
07:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. Device 3290
07:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. Device 3298
08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

`rfkill list all`:

```
0: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`dmesg | grep -i firmware`

```
[    0.305939] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.566226] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness
[    0.566570] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness
[    2.099004] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness
```

`sudo lshw -class network`:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Ralink corp.
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f0210000-f021ffff
```

`ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 84:34:97:93:47:a4  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1072 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1072 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
         RX bytes:87792 (87.7 KB)  TX bytes:87792 (87.7 KB)
```

`iwconfig`:

```
lo        no wireless extensions
```

Comment: @LeandroGuedes - this report maybe your issue - please can you have a look and run through some of the suggestions - add any thoughts and findings you have to your question.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1049466

Comment: ... and this AU Q&A seems also to apply to you as well - thus this may be a duplicate - http://askubuntu.com/questions/233442/hp-4770s-ralink-3290-wireless-not-working-on-12-10?rq=1

Comment: @fossfreedom Thanks. Step #8 on that forum doesn't work, and make my system incredibly slow. I'll try to uninstall the 3.7 kernell or reinstall the system.

Comment: @fossfreedom system back, I removed the 3,7 kernel :) but the wifi is still dead.

Comment: @LeandroGuedes - if you are willing to play & reinstall stuff - can I suggest you try the 13.04 daily release build - it will come with kernel 3.8.

Comment: @fossfreedom I got the 13,4 installed now. Should I open another question, or edit this one with the different outputs?

Comment: definitely not - 13.04 Q's are off-topic (http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do) - if 13.04 is not working for you, then 12.10 + someother fix will need to be done.  Note - I saw that you installed 3.7 kernel - however the problem report quoted kernel 3.6.11.

Comment: @fossfreedom But the same thing happened with 3.7. I'm gonna downgrade to 12.10 again

Comment: Well, I`m still trying to solve this. If anyone has a suggestion, I appreciate.

Comment: with ubuntu 13.04 - did you copy the firmware as per the the question http://askubuntu.com/questions/240553/how-do-i-install-ra3290-bin-wireless-driver-into-lib-firmware