# Bluetooth adapter not found HP 250 g2 Ubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: 14.04, laptop, bluetooth, hp

On boot there are two messages -

```
Bluetooth: error in firmware loading err = -110, len = 440, size = 4076
```

and

```
Bluetooth : Loading patch file failed
```

and in the bluetooth settings it says "no bluetooth adapters found"

I tried this from other's posts

**`sudo lshw -class network`**

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 07
       serial: fc:15:b4:04:50:d8
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:43 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c2600000-c2600fff memory:c2400000-c2403fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 28:e3:47:0c:03:8c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.13.0-24-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:18 memory:c2500000-c257ffff memory:afb00000-afb0ffff
```

**`lspci`**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

**`rfkill list`**

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN

    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Here are results from lspci etc when bluetooth worked again recently after a reinstall... again not working now.

```
dee@Ted:~$ sudo lshw -class network 
[sudo] password for dee: 
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface 
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller 
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
       physical id: 0 
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0 
       logical name: eth0 
       version: 07 
       serial: fc:15:b4:04:50:d8 
       size: 10Mbit/s 
       capacity: 100Mbit/s 
       width: 64 bits 
       clock: 33MHz 
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation 
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s 
       resources: irq:42 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c2600000-c2600fff memory:c2400000-c2403fff 
  *-network 
       description: Wireless interface 
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter 
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros 
       physical id: 0 
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0 
       logical name: wlan0 
       version: 01 
       serial: 28:e3:47:0c:03:8c 
       width: 64 bits 
       clock: 33MHz 
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless 
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.13.0-24-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn 
       resources: irq:18 memory:c2500000-c257ffff memory:afb00000-afb0ffff
```

dmesg

```
[    1.340354] scsi0 : ahci 
[    1.340434] scsi1 : ahci 
[    1.340499] scsi2 : ahci 
[    1.340558] scsi3 : ahci 
[    1.340615] scsi4 : ahci 
[    1.340669] scsi5 : ahci 
[    1.340703] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xc2717000 port 0xc2717100 irq 43 
[    1.340705] ata2: DUMMY 
[    1.340708] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xc2717000 port 0xc2717200 irq 43 
[    1.340709] ata4: DUMMY 
[    1.340710] ata5: DUMMY 
[    1.340711] ata6: DUMMY 
[    1.496003] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci 
[    1.628521] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024 
[    1.628524] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0 
[    1.628748] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found 
[    1.628828] hub 1-1:1.0: 6 ports detected 
[    1.660105] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300) 
[    1.663546] ata1.00: ATA-8: TOSHIBA MQ01ABF050, AM002C, max UDMA/100 
[    1.663552] ata1.00: 976773168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA 
[    1.668556] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100 
[    1.668775] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      TOSHIBA MQ01ABF0 AM00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5 
[    1.668918] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0 
[    1.668925] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/465 GiB) 
[    1.668929] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks 
[    1.669027] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off 
[    1.669031] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00 
[    1.669111] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA 
[    1.740199] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci 
[    1.802611]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 
[    1.803233] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk 
[    1.872677] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024 
[    1.872694] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0 
[    1.872926] hub 2-1:1.0: USB hub found 
[    1.873051] hub 2-1:1.0: 6 ports detected 
[    1.988384] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300) 
[    1.990373] ata3.00: ATAPI: hp       DVDRAM GU90N, U900, max UDMA/100 
[    1.992501] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100 
[    1.996466] scsi 2:0:0:0: CD-ROM            hp       DVDRAM GU90N     U900 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5 
[    1.999677] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 24x/24x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray 
[    1.999680] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20 
[    1.999831] sr 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0 
[    1.999989] sr 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5 
[    2.040463] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd 
[    2.113889] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=5776 
[    2.113893] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2 
[    2.113895] usb 3-3: Product: HP Truevision HD 
[    2.113898] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: DDTPN019I5XGZ0 
[    2.113899] usb 3-3: SerialNumber: 200901010001 
[    2.124496] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2394.560 MHz 
[    2.212507] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 7.5, id: 0x1c0b1, caps: 0xf00133/0x240000/0xa2400, board id: 2665, fw id: 1458825 
[    2.248856] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5 
[    2.284669] usb 3-4: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd 
[    2.301993] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=3121 
[    2.301996] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0 
[    2.826375] EXT4-fs (sda2): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem 
[    2.826378] EXT4-fs (sda2): write access will be enabled during recovery 
[    3.125430] Switched to clocksource tsc 
[    3.159141] EXT4-fs (sda2): orphan cleanup on readonly fs 
[    3.159285] EXT4-fs (sda2): 5 orphan inodes deleted 
[    3.159287] EXT4-fs (sda2): recovery complete 
[    3.339753] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null) 
[    3.782520] random: nonblocking pool is initialized 
[   12.226764] Adding 4083708k swap on /dev/sda3.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:4083708k FS 
[   12.353946] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready 
[   12.391756] systemd-udevd[307]: starting version 204 
[   12.535266] lp: driver loaded but no devices found 
[   12.550689] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver 
[   12.560025] wmi: Mapper loaded 
[   12.571573] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810 
[   12.573796] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X 
[   12.589978] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 2048M 
[   12.589983] checking generic (b0000000 408000) vs hw (b0000000 10000000) 
[   12.589985] fb: conflicting fb hw usage inteldrmfb vs EFI VGA - removing generic driver 
[   12.590010] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25 
[   12.595850] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17 
[   12.595872] NET: Registered protocol family 31 
[   12.595874] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized 
[   12.595882] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized 
[   12.595885] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized 
[   12.595889] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized 
[   12.597851] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb 
[   12.608654] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain 
[   12.648717] ath: phy0: WB335 1-ANT card detected 
[   12.648722] ath: phy0: Set BT/WLAN RX diversity capability 
[   12.657771] ath: phy0: Enable LNA combining 
[   12.657860] i915 0000:00:02.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X 
[   12.657876] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013). 
[   12.657878] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query. 
[   12.658016] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem 
[   12.659582] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x43 
[   12.659586] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6a 
[   12.659587] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map 
[   12.659590] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00 
[   12.659591] ath: Regpair used: 0x6a 
[   12.669305] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht' 
[   12.670529] ieee80211 phy0: Atheros AR9565 Rev:1 mem=0xffffc90010800000, irq=18 
[   12.705099] kvm: disabled by bios 
[   12.708927] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device 
[   12.863649] intel_rapl: domain uncore energy ctr 231228:231228 not working, skip 
[   12.879766] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k 
[   12.879795] usb 3-4: USB disconnect, device number 3 
[   12.884698] input: HP WMI hotkeys as /devices/virtual/input/input6 
[   12.935958] type=1400 audit(1401132430.151:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=389 comm="apparmor_parser" 
[   12.935962] type=1400 audit(1401132430.151:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=389 comm="apparmor_parser" 
[   12.935965] type=1400 audit(1401132430.151:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=389 comm="apparmor_parser" 
[   12.936370] type=1400 audit(1401132430.151:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=366 comm="apparmor_parser" 
[   12.936377] type=1400 audit(1401132430.151:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=366 comm="apparmor_parser" 
[   12.936381] type=1400 audit(1401132430.151:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=366 comm="apparmor_parser" 
[   12.936388] type=1400 audit(1401132430.151:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=389 comm="apparmor_parser" 
[   12.936391] type=1400 audit(1401132430.151:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=389 comm="apparmor_parser" 
[   12.936603] type=1400 audit(1401132430.151:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=389 comm="apparmor_parser" 
[   12.936901] type=1400 audit(1401132430.151:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=366 comm="apparmor_parser" 
[   13.003378] Linux video capture interface: v2.00 
[   13.011016] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device HP Truevision HD (0bda:5776) 
[   13.016106] input: HP Truevision HD as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.0/input/input7 
[   13.016243] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo 
[   13.016244] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1) 
[   13.082190] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated: 
[   13.082191] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp) 
[   13.082193] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   13.082194] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   13.082195] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   13.082196] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   13.082198] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   13.149846] usb 3-4: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd 
[   13.498188] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 170x48 
[   13.500727] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device 
[   13.500728] i915 0000:00:02.0: registered panic notifier 
[   13.515337] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no) 
[   13.516546] acpi device:40: registered as cooling_device5 
[   13.517720] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input8 
[   13.518867] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0 
[   13.519112] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042f SystemIO conflicts with Region \PMIO 1 (20131115/utaddress-251) 
[   13.519119] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver 
[   13.519124] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 1 (20131115/utaddress-251) 
[   13.519128] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver 
[   13.519130] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 1 (20131115/utaddress-251) 
[   13.519134] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver 
[   13.519136] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich 
[   13.519343] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X 
[   13.538216] SKU: Nid=0x1d sku_cfg=0x40f41905 
[   13.538220] SKU: port_connectivity=0x1 
[   13.538221] SKU: enable_pcbeep=0x1 
[   13.538223] SKU: check_sum=0x00000004 
[   13.538224] SKU: customization=0x00000019 
[   13.538225] SKU: external_amp=0x0 
[   13.538226] SKU: platform_type=0x1 
[   13.538227] SKU: swap=0x0 
[   13.538229] SKU: override=0x1 
[   13.538442] autoconfig: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker 
[   13.538445]    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) 
[   13.538447]    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) 
[   13.538449]    mono: mono_out=0x0 
[   13.538450]    inputs: 
[   13.538452]      Mic=0x19 
[   13.538454]      Internal Mic=0x12 
[   13.538456] realtek: No valid SSID, checking pincfg 0x40f41905 for NID 0x1d 
[   13.538458] realtek: Enabling init ASM_ID=0x1905 CODEC_ID=10ec0282 
[   13.551178] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input11 
[   13.551285] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input10 
[   13.551376] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input9 
[   13.838794] [drm] Enabling RC6 states: RC6 on, RC6p on, RC6pp off 
[   13.953842] EXT4-fs (sda2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro 
[   14.520813] init: failsafe main process (637) killed by TERM signal 
[   14.945214] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized 
[   14.945227] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized 
[   14.945232] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11 
[   14.947897] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3 
[   14.947900] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast 
[   14.947910] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized 
[   15.551606] init: avahi-cups-reload main process (776) terminated with status 1 
[   16.738088] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: link down 
[   16.738138] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready 
[   16.738449] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready 
[   16.752740] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready 
[   16.759687] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready 
[   18.154149] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for address device command 
[   18.154180] ------------[ cut here ]------------ 
[   18.154189] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 0 at /build/buildd/linux-3.13.0/drivers/usb/host/xhci-ring.c:1572 handle_cmd_completion+0xe2a/0xe40() 
[   18.154190] Modules linked in: bnep rfcomm nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core videodev hp_wmi sparse_keymap snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_pcm intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm snd_page_alloc crct10dif_pclmul snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event crc32_pclmul snd_rawmidi ghash_clmulni_intel cryptd snd_seq arc4 joydev serio_raw ath9k ath9k_common ath9k_hw ath snd_seq_device snd_timer rtsx_pci_ms mac80211 lpc_ich snd memstick cfg80211 ath3k btusb bluetooth soundcore i915 drm_kms_helper mei_me mei drm i2c_algo_bit wmi parport_pc ppdev video lp parport mac_hid rtsx_pci_sdmmc psmouse ahci r8169 libahci rtsx_pci mii 
[   18.154235] CPU: 3 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/3 Not tainted 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu 
[   18.154237] Hardware name: Hewlett-Packard HP 250 G2 Notebook PC/218F, BIOS F.0C 01/08/2013 
[   18.154239]  0000000000000009 ffff88014f2c3da8 ffffffff81715ac4 0000000000000000 
[   18.154242]  ffff88014f2c3de0 ffffffff810676bd ffff880145297430 0000000000000003 
[   18.154244]  ffff8801452970e0 00000001452970e0 ffff880145188000 ffff88014f2c3df0 
[   18.154247] Call Trace: 0 
[   18.154280]  [<ffffffff810bf87d>] handle_irq_event+0x3d/0x60 
[   18.154283]  [<ffffffff810c2257>] handle_edge_irq+0x77/0x130 
[   18.154286]  [<ffffffff81015cde>] handle_irq+0x1e/0x30 
[   18.154290]  [<ffffffff817287cd>] do_IRQ+0x4d/0xc0 
[   18.154293]  [<ffffffff8171df6d>] common_interrupt+0x6d/0x6d 
[   18.154294]  <EOI>  [<ffffffff815c95e2>] ? cpuidle_enter_state+0x52/0xc0 
[   18.154300]  [<ffffffff815c9709>] cpuidle_idle_call+0xb9/0x1f0 
[   18.154303]  [<ffffffff8101ceae>] arch_cpu_idle+0xe/0x30 
[   18.154306]  [<ffffffff810beb85>] cpu_startup_entry+0xc5/0x290 
[   18.154309]  [<ffffffff81040fc8>] start_secondary+0x218/0x2c0 
[   18.154311] ---[ end trace a7a9af493000c6d0 ]--- 
[   18.235052] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning 
[   18.244533] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning 
[   18.358357] usb 3-4: Device not responding to set address. 
[   18.559641] wlan0: authenticate with 20:0c:c8:8b:26:10 
[   18.562445] usb 3-4: device not accepting address 4, error -71 
[   18.580402] wlan0: send auth to 20:0c:c8:8b:26:10 (try 1/3) 
[   18.582645] wlan0: authenticated 
[   18.586524] wlan0: associate with 20:0c:c8:8b:26:10 (try 1/3) 
[   18.591115] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 20:0c:c8:8b:26:10 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2) 
[   18.591180] wlan0: associated 
[   18.591194] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready 
[   18.591452] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: GB 
[   18.594156] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x833a 
[   18.594160] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code 
[   18.594161] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search 
[   18.594163] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37 
[   18.594164] ath: Country alpha2 being used: GB 
[   18.594165] ath: Regpair used: 0x37 
[   18.594166] ath: regdomain 0x833a dynamically updated by country IE 
[   18.594187] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: GB 
[   18.594188] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp) 
[   18.594190] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm) 
[   18.594191] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm) 
[   18.594192] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm) 
[   18.594194] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm) 
[   18.594195] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm) 
[   18.629528] wlan0: deauthenticating from 20:0c:c8:8b:26:10 by local choice (reason=2) 
[   18.638171] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain 
[   18.638222] wlan0: authenticate with 20:0c:c8:8b:26:10 
[   18.653708] wlan0: send auth to 20:0c:c8:8b:26:10 (try 1/3) 
[   18.653873] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated: 
[   18.653877] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp) 
[   18.653880] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   18.653883] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   18.653885] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   18.653886] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   18.653888] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   18.655987] wlan0: authenticated 
[   18.658557] wlan0: associate with 20:0c:c8:8b:26:10 (try 1/3) 
[   18.667784] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 20:0c:c8:8b:26:10 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2) 
[   18.667834] wlan0: associated 
[   18.667887] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: GB 
[   18.670393] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x833a 
[   18.670396] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code 
[   18.670398] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search 
[   18.670399] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37 
[   18.670400] ath: Country alpha2 being used: GB 
[   18.670401] ath: Regpair used: 0x37 
[   18.670403] ath: regdomain 0x833a dynamically updated by country IE 
[   18.670424] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: GB 
[   18.670425] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp) 
[   18.670426] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm) 
[   18.670427] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm) 
[   18.670429] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm) 
[   18.670430] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm) 
[   18.670431] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm) 
[   18.674582] usb 3-4: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd 
[   18.692000] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=3121 
[   18.692005] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0 
[   95.322810] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain 
[   95.331089] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated: 
[   95.331096] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp) 
[   95.331100] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   95.331103] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   95.331106] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   95.331108] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 
[   95.331111] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) 

[  112.130948] wlan0: authenticate with 20:0c:c8:8b:26:10 
[  112.155159] wlan0: send auth to 20:0c:c8:8b:26:10 (try 1/3) 
[  112.747968] wlan0: authenticated 
[  112.750559] wlan0: associate with 20:0c:c8:8b:26:10 (try 1/3) 
[  113.161405] wlan0: associate with 20:0c:c8:8b:26:10 (try 2/3) 
[  113.923564] wlan0: associate with 20:0c:c8:8b:26:10 (try 3/3) 
[  114.166216] wlan0: association with 20:0c:c8:8b:26:10 timed out 
[  115.522610] wlan0: authenticate with 20:0c:c8:8b:26:10 
[  115.543234] wlan0: send auth to 20:0c:c8:8b:26:10 (try 1/3) 
[  131.424574] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm) 
[  131.424578] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm) 
[  131.424581] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm) 
[  131.424585] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm) 
[  131.424589] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
```

Comment: That bluetooth adapter what is it? A wireless card? Bluetooth dongle to use with keyboard mouse ?

Comment: No. I think its the internal bluetooth on the laptop. It worked once but then stopped and now can't be found.

Comment: duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/256320/hp-2000-wireless-dont-work-with-ubuntu-12-10

Comment: Could you run `lsmod`?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to this issue is that you may have bluetooth disabled in the BIOS, or EFI. If that is not the issue; what you should do is determine if this is a hardware failure by booting up another distribution or operating system in which you can test whether Bluetooth works in that instance. If it happens that this is not a hardware failure, then you should report a bug in Launchpad

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Which is a great help to the open source community.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar Bluetooth hardware.  A Lenovo G50-70 with an Atheros Bluetooth card in it, running Kubuntu 14.04. From lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc.
```

I was also getting the failure to load error=-110 as well.

What I have found is the `/lib/firmware/ath3k-1.fw` shipped with kubuntu is not working.  The file shipped has a MD5 sum of `1211fa34c09e10ba48381586b7c3883d  ath3k-1.fw`.
The file you need has the MD5 sum `24cfee59a24f336dfae838a0de6445a0  ath3k-1.fw`
and can be extracted from `linux-firmware_1.79_all.deb`.

That solved my problem four or five months ago.  Wanting to use Bluetooth again today and its both broken and these steps don't fix it anymore.  I think its a new kernel since I fixed it the first time, I am now on:

```
3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I know its a new kernel from when I fixed it, but what I mean is I think that change is what killed Bluetooth again.

So, after two days of hair pulling, going over my steps again and again, I installed a BIOS update, original was from Dec 2013, new one is from Aug 2014 (I think, its either the 11th of Aug, or the 8th of Nov... your choice!)  I logged in ready to resume the battle, and lo and behold, the funky B logo is in my program bar, and clicking on it brings up a list of BT devices in my area!  Turns out it also kills my WiFi connection though, which did not happen last time I fixed things!